# Is it possible to disable TLS 1.1 in domino 9?

Tags: ssl, ibm-domino

Is it possible to disable TLS 1.1 on Domino 9 ? The server is IBM Domino (r) Server (64 Bit) (Release 9.0.1FP8 for Windows/64).

With the same logic that setting configuration **SSL_Disable_TLS_10=1** in NOTES.INI disable TLS **1.0**, is there an option for disabling TLS **1.1** ?